# I the backtick (`) a valid replacement for a quote (") in HTML?

Tags: html, syntax, quotes, backticks

Is this `<html lang="en">` the same as `` <html lang=`en`> ``?

Comment: Sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the circumstance where you would need to use backticks?

Comment: Why would you think so? Have you tried reading the HTML spec? https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/syntax.html#syntax-attributes

Comment: No, it is not...

Comment: @deceze The spec answered the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, backticks (`) are not allowed.

Only single quotes ('), double quotes (") and no quotes () are allowed. . [W3C specification](http://%20w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/%E2%80%A6%20%E2%80%93%20deceze%E2%99%A6%204%20mins%20ago)